# node-inspector does not debug - it stops execution immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I am running node.js v0.10.0.  I also just installed node-inspector.  I use the --debug-brk and test my javascript (nothing fancy - just 1 file):

```
console.log('here');
console.log('here');
console.log('here');
```

I connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080?port=5858`, and see my script as above, and execution is stopped on the first line.  However, when I click continue (the |> icon), execution just stops.  It does not log 'here' in console, or command window.  'step' does the same thing.

Any thoughts as to why I cannot debug?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/issues/152

Answer (score 0):

As @robertklep stated, there is an issue documented on https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/issues/152 with the solution.  The last check-in was 10 months ago, so it does not seem that a fix is coming soon.  Fork the repo, then:

```
npm install -g .
```

Then run as normal: `node-inspector`

Answer (score 0):

Some problems also can arrives if you using adblock or so